# Mix-link code built with /vmg and without /vmg with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Visual studio generates different code if compiled with `/vmg` compared to without `/vmg`. In my solution, there are multiple of source files. Some of them are compiled with `/vmg` and others are without `/vmg`. Now from those source files, we get different executables.

The problem is some of the executable work and others crash. It seems that the workable executables are using the code with `/vmg`. The crashed executables are using the code without `/vmg`. Why are there such differences?

My program needs to link 3rdparty libraries. I cannot get the version built with `/vmg`. How can I handle that?

Comment: Looks like mixing /vmg and non-/vmg code leads to some really unobvious errors possible at every operation with member pointers. So it would be nice if MSVC would give error in this case similar to the one about different _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL.